# Question mark after JS array variable, but before .length

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm trying to understand this piece of code:

```
!isLoading && !QRCodes?.length ? (.....
```

What is the role of `?` in `!QRCodes?.length`? Wouldn't be the statement false anyway, when there's no `QRCodes`?

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: "Wouldn't be the statement false anyway?" - nope, it would be "Uncaught Type Error: cannot read 'length' property of undefined/null".

Comment: The question mark is used to check if `QRCodes` is undefined before accessing the length property, so to prevent a possible exception. Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score -1):

!isLoading means if not loading and the QRCodes length is 0 display the thing after the (...
the question mark in QRCodes?.length means that get length if exists